# MATLAB startup.m ignores cd?

Tags: matlab

in my startup.m-file I call a script `init.m`. In this init file I determine the folder containing this file, want to set the current directory to this folder and continue with some other initialization stuff.
But when I start Matlab, the file will be executed, but the `cd` command seems to be ignored and the directory won't get changed. Does somebody know why? I.e. the matlabpath variable is extended by the subfolders....

startup.m:

```
run 'D:\FloatingZone\mscrystalgrowth\trunk\MATLAB\FzKameradaten\FzCameraEvaluation\init.m';
```

init.m

```
% get path to folder containing this function
folder=mfilename('fullpath');
file=mfilename();
folder=folder(1:end-length(file));
% change folder
cd(folder);
% add subfolder to the top of the MATLAB path
addpath(genpath('Tools'));
```

Comment: P.S. you should also look at `folder = fileparts ( mfilename('fullpath') )`

Comment: I think this would be a decent way to do it:

`addpath('D:\FloatingZone\mscrystalgrowth\trunk\MATLAB\FzKameradaten\FzCameraEvaluation')`
`init`
`rmpath('D:\FloatingZone\mscrystalgrowth\trunk\MATLAB\FzKameradaten\FzCameraEvaluation')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB did exactly what you told it; there's nothing special about the startup scripts.

From the documentation for the `run` command:

> `run` changes to the folder that contains the script, executes it, and resets back to the original folder. If the script itself changes folders, then `run` does not revert to the original folder, unless *scriptname* changes to the folder in which this script resides.

So your `cd` command didn't actually do anything, `run` had already changed the directory.  And then changed it back, exactly as expected.

Comment: is there any reason why you cant just `cd` to the folder and execute `init.m` as you would a normal function?

Comment: Ok. so I put my script in a subfolder and change to the parent folder within the script, then the path change won't be reverted. inconvenient and messy. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you not do: `addpath ( genpath ( pwd ) )`

Comment: @matlabgui:
this init.m file is not only used in the startup.m file. This should be a common init-function that initializes a simulation enviroment. But currently I work every day with this enviroment, so I wanted to add it to the startup sequence

Comment: @paul_schaefer: The better way is to have two commands in `startup.m`.  `cd 'D:\FloatingZone\mscrystalgrowth\trunk\MATLAB\FzKameradaten\FzCameraEvaluation'; init` as matlabgui shows in his answer.  The total length is no more than for using `run`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want your startup to do.  As already pointed out `run` is working correctly.

Alternative `startup.m`

```
if isdeployed == false
  cd 'D:\FloatingZone\mscrystalgrowth\trunk\MATLAB\FzKameradaten\FzCameraEvaluation\'
  init();
end
```

function `init.m` stored in your `FzCameraEvaluation\` folder.

```
function init
  addpath ( genpath ( '../Tools' ) );
end
```

Does that work?